# NullPointerException error occurs while converting byte[] to ImageIcon

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, arrays, jlabel

I am trying to put byte[] to JLabel on netbeans maven Project. I read some solutions and then implement it for me. However when I start application it gives me error lists such as;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:228)
    at org.tutev.envanterys.gui.finger.FrmFinger.btnShowImagesActionPerformed(FrmFinger.java:104)
    at org.tutev.envanterys.gui.finger.FrmFinger.access$000(FrmFinger.java:29)
    at org.tutev.envanterys.gui.finger.FrmFinger$1.actionPerformed(FrmFinger.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
```

Could you please kindly help me where is my mistake and how can I avoid this? Here is my code:

```
 try {
            Finger finger = new Finger();
            FingerService fingerService = new FingerService();

            finger = fingerService.getImage(Long.parseLong("1"));

            byte[] image1 = finger.getImage1();

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(image1);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bais);

            lblFinger1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmFinger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

When I debug application I see that `byte[]` and `bais` has data but `BufferedImage img` is **null**.

Comment: I'll admit, I got to the part where you said "I am trying to put byte[] to JLabel.." and  my mind screamed "WHY!?"

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your data really an image data.

As API documentation: ImageIO read method's explanation is;

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied
>   InputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those
>   currently registered. The InputStream is wrapped in an
>   ImageInputStream. **If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to
>   read the resulting stream, null is returned**. The current cache
>   settings from getUseCacheand getCacheDirectory will be used to control
>   caching in the ImageInputStream that is created.
>
> This method does not attempt to locate ImageReaders that can read
>   directly from an InputStream; that may be accomplished using
>   IIORegistry and ImageReaderSpi.
>
> This method does not close the provided InputStream after the read
>   operation has completed; it is the responsibility of the caller to
>   close the stream, if desired.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File))